# Flash ActionScript 3 runtime SecurityError

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have swf that loads swf, which loads another swf(video player).

Is there a trick in publish settings?  everything works fine on my local machine, when I upload it on the sever error happen and video doesnt load

> SecurityError: Error #2148: SWF file
>   http:// (URL where Site is
>   hosted)/video.swf cannot access local
>   resource
>   file:///Macintosh%20HD/Users/..flash.flv.
>   Only local-with-filesystem and trusted
>   local SWF files may access local
>   resources.    at
>   flash.net::NetStream/play()   at
>   fl.video::VideoPlayer/http://www.adobe.com/2007/flash/flvplayback/internal::_play()
>     at
>   fl.video::VideoPlayer/http://www.adobe.com/2007/flash/flvplayback/internal::_setUpStream()
>     at
>   fl.video::VideoPlayer/http://www.adobe.com/2007/flash/flvplayback/internal::_load()
>     at fl.video::VideoPlayer/load()     at
>   fl.video::FLVPlayback/doContentPathConnect()

Comment: That's surely not the full error, is it?

Comment: No, I wasnt sure if was relevant, but here it is now.

Comment: Is the error thrown when you try to access the flv/video player or the swf that holds it (the swf that gets loaded by the main swf, which contains the video player) ? 

Eitherway, here's a quick checklist, in case you access content from another domain, maybe it helps:
1. you have a crossdomain.xml setup
2. if you're using the flash ide, you have 'Access network only' for Local Playback Security under the Flash tab in Publish Settings.
3. if you've got the above setup, check that your loader has a LoaderContext object with checkPolicyFile set to true.

HTH

Comment: Problem is with the flv/video player. Ive checked publish settings, and nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to setup a crossdomain.xml to allow the one SWF access to the other in the production environment.

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/articles/crossdomain_policy_file_spec.html

Answer (score 0):

Here's a couple things. Remember your security policy document and your SWF publishing settings. I hope these resources help.

**Cross Domain Policy** "Use master-only"

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.adobe.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
  <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="master-only"/>
  <allow-access-from domain="*" to-ports="*"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

**Your SWF Publishing Settings**
[alt text http://ashcraftband.com/myspace/videodnd/network.jpg](http://ashcraftband.com/myspace/videodnd/network.jpg)

**Reference**
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/fplayer9-10_security.html
http://jodieorourke.com/view.php?id=108&blog=news